# Cant make Django execute only one query with multiple joins using .all()... or even .raw(sql) methods

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm new to Django and wanted to give it a try to convert an already existing PHP application to Django.

But I'm already stuck creating a queryset over multiple joined tables so only one sql query would be executed.

I'm using a MySql DB.

I already managed to create a view that reduces the amount of queries with .all(), .filter, .order_by and multiple .select_related but couldn't get it to make only one sql query call.

So I thought I should maybe use the .raw(sql) method, but even using this approach made Django execute hundrets of single sql queries not respecting the joins.

Maybe you could help me a bit getting this, normally simple thing, to work in Django?

Here's my original SQL query which works absolutely fine if run in MySql and gives a nice resultset:

```
SELECT
                `hosts`.`id`,
                `hosts`.`hostname`,

                `domains`.`domain_name`,

                `hosts`.`description`,
                `hosts`.`installation_by_company_id`,
                `hosts`.`care_by_company_id`,
                `hosts`.`system_care_by_department_id`,
                `hosts`.`system_care_accounting_type_id`,

                `os`.`operatingsystem`,
                `os`.`lsbdistcodename`,
                `os`.`lsbdistrelease`,
                `os`.`lsbmajdistrelease`,

                `system_care_department`.`department_name` AS `system_care_department`,
                `additional_software_care_department`.`department_name` AS `additional_software_care_department`,
                `system_installation_company`.`company_name` AS `system_installation_company`,
                `system_installation_company`.`company_abrebreation` AS `system_installation_company_abrebreation`
            FROM
                `hosts`
            JOIN
                `domains` ON `hosts`.`domain_id` = `domains`.`id`
            JOIN
                `hosts_fix_data_scans` ON `hosts_fix_data_scans`.`host_id` = `hosts`.`id`
            JOIN
                `os` ON `os`.`id` = `hosts_fix_data_scans`.`os_id`
            JOIN
                `companies_departments` ON `companies_departments`.`id` = `hosts`.`system_care_by_department_id`
            JOIN
                `companies_departments` AS `system_care_department` ON `system_care_department`.`id` = `hosts`.`system_care_by_department_id`
            JOIN
                `companies_departments` AS `additional_software_care_department`  ON `additional_software_care_department`.`id` = `hosts`.`additional_software_care_by_department_id`
            JOIN
                `companies` AS `system_installation_company` ON `system_installation_company`.id = `hosts`.`installation_by_company_id`
            WHERE
                `hosts`.`offline` = 0

            ORDER BY `system_care_department`;
```

This was my first approach which was leading to many (as many as entries in the hosts table = 141) additional queries to the os table and one additional query to the software_updates table:

```
machines = SinfraHosts.objects.all().filter(offline=0).order_by('system_care_by_department').select_related('domain').select_related('last_fix_data_scan').select_related('installation_by_company').select_related('system_care_by_department').select_related('care_by_company')
```

OK, but how about using my SQL query directly with this approach:

```
machines = SinfraSqlHosts.objects.raw(sql)
```

Things got even worse: While my first approach resulted in 143 single executed sql queries, the approach using the SQL-query directly via the .raw(sql) method resulted in unbelievable 284 single executed sql queries!

Could please someone help me get the above query run as one single query in my view and return the correct resultset?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your models code so people can understand how your database tables are created and with what relationships.

**Tip**: You don't need to use all and filter in a single query, also for select_related(), instead of using it for multiple columns one by one, you can just use it once and add column names separated by comma `select_related('domain', 'last_fix_data_scan', 'installation_by_company')`

Comment: Many thanks for the tip, Asim! That's really useful.

And I now found thee solution for executing the sql query directly using connection.cursor()

I think posting all the involved tables here would not really help.
The above sql query explains all dependencies and the use of "virtual" fields that do not exist in the tables exactly.
Someone who doesn't understand the query will also not be able to translate it to a Django queryset.
I must admit, this is probably a question for pros.

But it's probably generally the better solution to use raw sql queries directly.

Thanks again.